# Set default language for HTML input`s

Tags: html, layout, input, keyboard

How to set default keyboard layout for input boxes, for example when the page gets loaded, we can type in an input text with another keyboard language else than English?

Comment: ??? plase explain better your problem explaining the whole situation and environment you work in.

Comment: Are you talking about, for example, virtual keyboards on touch devices?

Comment: No i just try to prvent user to pressing ctrl +shift to change the language,ijust set a defualt keyboard layout for an input box

Comment: @Pierre :) look at answer i configure the meta information and use the lang attribute , it work perfectly for me ;)

Comment: if it worked, please check the holo tickbox next to the answer, thanks

Comment: Well, I'm glad it works. I wouldn't have bet a penny on this. =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switching between input methods between HTML input fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371473/switching-between-input-methods-between-html-input-fields)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd think about the `lang` attribute. But this is meta-information, I'm really not sure the browser will do anything with it. Never tried it myself.

```
<input lang="is" ...>
```

Comment: It does not affect keyboard settings at all.

Comment: I tried it in codepen, made an input with lang="en" and lang="ru", i have both English and Russian in gboard on Android, and it had no effect either in Firefox for Android or Chrome for Android. I see that duolingo (native app) manages to hint which language to use for text input but maybe that's not yet available via Web APIs. It's a shame, it's super useful when creating language apps

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's possible to catch a `keyCode` of the button, that was pressed, with javascript and then replace the symbol to the appropriate symbol from array.
This code helps to understand how to catch a keyCode (it does not depend on keyboard language)

```
<form>
Char: <input type="text" id="char" size="15" /> Keycode: <input type="text" id="keycode" size="15" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

var charfield=document.getElementById("char")
charfield.onkeydown=function(e){
var e=window.event || e
document.getElementById("keycode").value=e.keyCode
}

</script>
```