# Can I set input language of a textbox or textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building an Urdu language website which, let's say, is similar to a blogging website. I want to enforce users to make posts in no language other than Urdu.

One solution I have in my mind is to manually capture each key pressed in Javascript and display its alternate in Urdu in the textbox. Something like this:

```
'A'-> 'ا' , 'B' -> 'ب'
```

I dont find it an efficient solution at all and would like to know if there is some sort of plug-in that I could use that sets the input language of a textbox? Or even if I must write a code of my own, do you have a solution other than one above?

Comment: you can look through second comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773120/set-defualt-language-for-html-inputs

Comment: That's already a solution that I have in my mind. But I was hoping there was a better way to do it.

Comment: I tried to achieve your logic but this is not perfect yet: http://jsfiddle.net/dqx9zqm1/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to me it is possible using regex : 
with the help of [the wikipedia page of the urdu alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urdu_alphabet) you can get the unicode range of Urdu language which are : 
[\u0600-\u06FF] , [\u0750-\u077F] , [\uFB50-\uFDFF] , [\uFE70-\uFEFF]

You can try something like that : bind a jquery event when a key is pressed, get the key string, test if it is Urdu, add the char if it is, do nothing if it isn't:

```
$('#yourTextArea').bind('keydown',function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation(); // stop propagating the key pressed
    var TextAreaVal = $('#yourTextArea').val()
    var urduRegex = /[\u0600-\u06FF]|[\u0750-\u077F]|[\uFB50-\uFDFF]|[\uFE70-\uFEFF]/;
    CharToTest = String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode); // get the char related to the key pressed
    if(urduRegex.test(CharToTest)) // if urdu
    {$('#yourTextArea').val(TextAreaVal + ChartoTest )} // add char to the textarea
    else
    {return;} // do nothing
}
```

[NOT TESTED] though I am sure you can work something around that...

Comment: And I'll appreciate if others didn't delete their answers. I'd like to keep my options open.

Comment: @TahreemIqbal The problem with this solution is that if you move your cursor to the middle of a sentence and attempt to insert something, it will still be appended to the end of the sentence. Additionally, it only stops a user from using non-Urdu characters. It doesn't actually convert roman characters to Urdu characters, so you would have to require your users to have an Urdu keyboard program installed.

Comment: @khalid13, if it is the problem, you can add an onchange event to the text zone to check if the new value are allowed. + the initial statement is _I want to enforce users to make posts in no language other than Urdu_ .

Comment: @khalid13 that's a valid argument. And not only that, there's also a problem of capturing multiple keydowns for a character. Like if small 'a' represents 'ا' and capital A represents 'آ' then I'll also have to capture shift+a keys and this will only go more complicated from there.

Comment: I could provide the setup for the software that enables Urdu language on the website and tell users to first install it before making posts. But that's not user friendly. I can't believe there is no plug in that solves this problem.

Comment: yes you are right, so you should then go for the `onchange` event that target the text area, then get the whole value and check if it validate the regex, if not put back the old value the text area

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for. For other people who might work on Urdu language in future, following are great Urdu editors available online.

https://www.branah.com/urduphonetic

http://www.lipikaar.com/online-editor/urdu-typing

They seem to be easily integrate-able with my website. Great stuff, really. Saved me from reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot be done using HTML, CSS or JavaScript... Use google input tools to do it http://www.google.co.in/inputtools/

Comment: I'm aware of google input tools. I installed them yesterday but how do I integrate it with my website?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Basically, you need to capture they keycode value on each keypress.

This link describes further how to intercept and change an entered value:

[Changing the keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604930/changing-the-keypress)

Comment: That's already a solution that I have in my mind. But I was hoping there was a better way to do it.