# change input character to other character

Tags: javascript

I have an input text field that users should type their name in it (kind of).
I see in a website that every letter I type it changes the letter immediately to another character in my own language. for instance it changes the "D" in English to "ی".
I want the same thing.
How can I achieve this? should I use JavaScript and change every key code on keydown event?

Comment: Yes, that would be one possible solution. Do you have an example of where this is happening, though? Such solutions are often quite invasive.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773120/set-defualt-language-for-html-inputs

Comment: For those how has Persian language there is a script I found in [this link](http://hasheminezhad.com/kblayout) and the creator of the script says it is easy to change to other languages as well by changing the array. I didn't need the details, I just load the script to my page and it worked perfectly, however I have another problem since mysql database refuse to store data send from this field. any idea?