# html form input default language - not working

Tags: html, forms, character-encoding, keyboard, lang

I am trying to set html form input's default language to Georgian.

i.e. when user starts typing input it should be in Georgian and user should not have to switch language from keyboard.

I tried using `lang="ka"` attribute on almost every element but it is not working. ("ka" is html language code reference for Georgian, and I do have Georgian keyboard installed).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ka">
  <head>
     <title></title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body lang="ka">
  <form lang="ka">
    სახელი:<br>
   <input lang="ka" type="text" name="firstname" >
   <br>
   გვარი:<br>
   <input lang="ka" type="text" name="lastname" >
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is due to your browser.You can also follow this.
[Set defualt language for HTML input`s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773120/set-defualt-language-for-html-inputs)

Comment: i use chrome.  will it work in firefox??

Comment: Please use latest version of chrome.