# Enforce input html language

Tags: html, css, input, attributes, lang

I wish to change the language of an input html to a different language(English) from my computer(Hebrew). is there a why to do that? tried lang ="en" but nothing changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default language for HTML input\`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773120/set-default-language-for-html-inputs)

Comment: Are you looking to change the keyboard layout or the spell checker?

Comment: I am trying to avoid the user to use alt+ shift.. so the input language automatically will change to English..

Comment: I'm sorry but this is impossible to do.