# Input method library in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ime

I was thinking that is impossible to use an input method (to enter foreign characters like Chinese or Japanese) in Javascript without an input box and that you can't intercept key events. I found [Input Method Editor API - W3C Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/ime-api/) but it's only a few months old, so browsers don't implement it for sure. Is there a library in pure Javascript that implements an input method that can be used instead?

**Update**: I found a library on sourceforge [jsime](http://jsime.sourceforge.net/), but it doesn't work at all when I test. In answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371473/switching-between-input-methods-between-html-input-fields), the library is mentionned but it's no longer there.

Comment: It's not a standalone library, but you might have a look at [MediaWiki's Narayam Extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Narayam)

Comment: @Bergi is there online demo for this extension somewhere?

Comment: The successor extension, ["universal language selector"](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UniversalLanguageSelector), is live on all Wikimedia wikis. In the user navigation bar there's a link which lets you choose input (and display) languages. Narayam itself seems to be active [on only a few wikis](http://wikiapiary.com/wiki/Extension:Narayam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery.IME](https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.ime)

https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.ime

It also has browser extension for Chrome and Firefox and customization options.

Comment: Thanks, it's probably the same plugin as mention in comment but extracted as separated project, this question is old and just as a side note this type of questions are off topic now on SO.